# Is there a way to show products in only one category and nowhere else in the website?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want to create a restricted category for over thirteen people. Is there a way to not have these products appear in anywhere else in the catalog, i.e. search, best sellers, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will find an extension with this functionality here.

https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

Using customer groups in Magento you are able to filter which products are displayed depending on customer attributes, such as age.